# Route 2nd domain to a specific page on my website w/ aws ec2 route53 s3 combo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Summary: AWS Route 53/S3 combo unable to point mySecondDomain.com to myFirstDomain.com/somePage with URL bar showing the former

Background: I've already bought and configure myFirstDomain.com to route to my EC2 instance via Route 53 (without using S3).

Now, I've bought mySecondDomain.com.  And I'd like to route it to myFirstDomain.com/somePage.

What I've done:
S3: Static website hosting; Use this bucket to host a website;

```xml
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>myFirstDomain.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>somePage</ReplaceKeyWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>301</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Route53: A-IPv4 address; Alias; Alias Target=(S3 bucket name)

Result I: When I go to mySecondDomain.com, I do get routed to myFirstDomain.com/somePage.  But the URL bar still shows "myFirstDomain.com/somePage".  I need it to show "mySecondDomain.com"

Result II: it goes to myFirstDomain.com/somePage/ with the trailing slash.  For some reason, myFirstDomain.com/somePage/ displays erroneously whereas myFirstDomain.com/somePage displays correctly.  Googling doesn't give me a lot of info as to what to do if one displays incorrectly.  Yea understand it's irrelevant under this title/question.  So it's just an optional question on here :)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In regards to Result II, I figured out that I'd better be adding heading slashes when doing referencing, e.g href="/some/path/file.jpg".  After making this modification, problem at Result II has now been resolved.

Comment: *When I go to mySecondDomain.com, I do get routed to myFirstDomain.com/somePage. But the URL bar still shows "myFirstDomain.com/somePage". I need it to show "mySecondDomain.com"* ... a redirect, by definition, changes the browser's address bar. If this is not desirable, then a "redirect" is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, If redirect is not what I'm looking for, then what should I look for?  I thought about this as well but not sure what other keywords I should use when googling.  I tried 'forward' but that also kinda means the same I think.  That is why on this page's title I say "route"...  Anyway, if you can give me a keyword to search, that'd be equally good for me, thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify why you framed this question in terms of example.org -> example.com/somepage?  If you don't want example.com/somepage in the address bar, then why does it matter that this is where the content comes from?  It sounds as if you have identified this as a useful strategy, but I wonder if your focus should be different or we need to back up a step to uncover your actual objective.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, thanks for helping!  Some more background: I have already created example.com using nodejs.  And then a friend asked me to help create a site under anotherExample.com.  So the plan is, instead of creating another EC2, I simply put it inside the same nodejs app on example.com/somepage.  And then use route53 to route it to example.com/somepage.  example.com/somepage and example.com are totally unrelated.  example.com/somepage is on example.com only for the convenience.  Esp because it's just a static site.